# working with 1000's of JSON files in Pyspark Databricks

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have around 2.5 k JSON files, each JSON file represents 1 row. With these files I need to do some extremely simple ETL and move them into a `curated` section of my datalake.

I iterate through my datalake and call my JSON files with a simple `.read` call I defined my JSON schema before hand.

I then do my ETL and try to write these files into a separate part of my datalake, however the writing part is *extremely* slow, it took 15 minutes to write a single file which was only a few hundred kb?

```
rp  = spark.read.json(paths, multiLine=True,schema=json_s).withColumn('path',F.input_file_name())

for iter in iterable:
    #do stuff
    # filter my sparkDF with .filter
    SparkDF_F = sparkDF.filter(...)
    sparkDF_F.write('path/filename.parquet')
```

I've attempted to use 'OPTIMIZE' and called it on my Path

```
%sql
OPTIMIZE delta.'dbfs:/mnt/raw/data/table'
```

which throws the following error.

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input 'dbfs:/mnt/raw/data/table' expecting {'SELECT', 'FROM', '
ADD', 'AS', 'TIMESTAMP', 'VERSION', 'ALL', 'ANY', 'DISTINCT', 
'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'BY', 'GROUPING', 'SETS', 'CUBE', 'ROLLUP', 'ORDER....
```

is anyone able to guide me to what I'm misunderstanding here?

Setup

- Azure Databricks
- 6.0
- Spark 2.4
- Python 3.6
- 42GB Cluster with 12 cores.
- 4 Nodes
- Azure Gen1 DataLake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. If the 2.5k JSON files are stored in the same folder. You can read them directly using the same folder path:

   rp  = spark.read.json(path_common, multiLine=True,schema=json_s).withColumn('path',F.input_file_name())

Then, you can apply the rp.filter in the whole dataframe as it is only one (without the need of iterating per each file)

2. Regarding to the documentation of Delta, you can optimize only a table (stored in dbfs) but not directly a DBFS file. So you can create the table with the directory pointed in dbfs and the use the optimize as suggested here in the documentation: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/optimize.html

Hope this helps

Comment: It does indeed, I will test first thing tomorrow. The jsons are not in the same folder unfortunately as we are storing them in a way that can be accessed for the next n years.

Comment: You really need the files in a single folder (or single parent folder that can be read from the top and then filtered). Even if it means making a temp copy first. Have you considered using a TTL on the file to meet the storing n years issue? That could allow you to structure the lake in a more traditional way. If not possible, I would consider azure functions over databricks. From the sounds of it the data is small - that cluster seems large for what it is doing?

Comment: @simon_dmorias apologies, my folder structure is `raw > year > month > day -- files` so all sit in with a defined number of days within the same year/month. I'm locked into using databricks due to client architecture, it is overkill, but it's part of a over-all bigger solution.

Comment: Ah ok. So you can just point to the root folder and import all. Then filter the dataframe to remove anything not required. Removing that loop will make the biggest difference. Spark is a bit rubbish with lots of small files, but should still perform way better that you have seen so far.

Comment: @simon_dmorias I still have single level loop, but it does perform orders of magnitude quicker than what it was performing last night, sadly in Databricks 6.0 + Python APIs no longer have access to dbfs file store - so using Pandas is also out of the question!

Comment: @Datanovice Could you please update your code again with single level loop you currently have? In the case you mention, you can read the json files partitioned by year, month and day too (and it the dataframe will be partitioned in those columns too)